# Using service in symfony

Tags: symfony

hi :) I'm stuck on an exercice i need to do using symfony 3, i think i miss something to understand how services work ... i don't need help with the code of the exercice just the logical part

The purpose of the exercice is to purge some elements in the database http://localhost/purge/x (x will be the parameter to decide what to remove in database in my case a number of days) no view needed

Ok so i do a route to the controller who call a method in the repository to give the results of all elements i need to remove and that's it !

But no the exercice ask me to use a method in the repository + a service but i don't understand what the service could do ?? i know how to do a service call it etc ... but in this case i just don't understand what i can give to my service to do ... and why is it better than using my first idea ?

Hope it's clear, Thanks :)

Comment: using a service for something like that seems like overkill to me.  Like you say, why not just use a repository method to give you the entities, then remove them in the controller.

Comment: I think it should do what your controller does currently, which is, as you said: *call a method in the repository to give the results of all elements i need to remove and that's it*. Except that it also should remove them from DB. In my opinion the exercise is about creating a service having dependencies on other services.

Comment: You mean the repository get the result and service used this result to remove it from the database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
class Purger
{
    public function __construct(EntityRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
    public function purge($days)
    {
        // Do what needs to be done
        $itemsToPurge = $this->repository->whatever...
    }
}
// Controller Action
$purger = $this->get('purger');
$purger->purge($days);

# services.yml
my_repository:
    class: MyBundle\Doctrine\MyRepository
    factory:   ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', 'getRepository']
    arguments: ['MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity']
purger:
    class: MyBundle\Purger
    arguments: ['@my_repository']
```

And for extra credit, define your controller as a service and inject the purger directly.  That may give you a better idea of the power of services and why the lesson exists.

Comment: Ok i understand what you explained but we didn't have seen how to build a function construct ... i don't think we are supposed to use it (same for factory in services.yml), we juste learned how to build a simple service it's why i don't see what my service can do (with what i supposed to know) :)

Comment: Better get clarification from your instructor.  What I posted is pretty much standard.

Comment: So here is the final answer we were suppose to :
- make a method in repository to catch the adverts to remove
- make a service who will use this method to remove the advert

The purpose was to make a service that we can call to purge other things than adverts